# Amazon/Flipkart product page parsing with Jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, hyperlink, web-scraping, jsoup

Amazon has different tags for different pages.

While parsing with Jsoup, one needs to specify the exact tag.

This is becoming a little difficult since one cannot inspect/enumerate all the different tags on all the pages.

Example: The below 3 pages have different tags for image and name:

[Product link 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OC0USA6)

Tags: "span#productTitle", "img#landingImage"

[Product link 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MA93VIM)

Tags: "span#btAsinTitle",  "img#main-image"

[Product link 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098266446X)

Tags: "#title_feature_div h1", "#coverArt_feature_div img"

Is there any library or code that handles all these different cases?

Comment: Can you post the tag examples?

Comment: I have added tags for each link

Comment: instead of using a parser, you could use a regex -- search everything before and after "title", everything surrounding "img" or "image"

Comment: That will still not solve the problem and I will still have to look for one regex and then another if not found. I was thinking of maybe this has been solved before somehow and there is an existing solution.

Comment: You could just use Jsoup, but provide the selector via configuration files (e.g xml) where you provide the url and a list of all the selectors that apply to that url. So even if something needs to be added/updated, it will be a minor change in the configuration files.

Comment: Thanks alkis. This is what I have done eventually :(